# Last value onlyadded to a list

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

I am facing one issue to add element to my list

Here is my code

```
def summary(request,):
    data = []
    values = {}
    fruits =  ['apple','mango','orange','grapes']
    for i in fruits:
        values['fruits'] = i
        values['count'] = calculating_count(i)
        data.append(values)
```

What I am expecting is that my data list need to come like this

```
data = [{'fruits':apple,'count':10},
        {'fruits':mango,'count':20},
        {'fruits':orange,'count':30},
        {'fruits':grapes,'count':40}]
```

But what I am getting it as

```
data = [{'fruits':grapes,'count':40},
        {'fruits':grapes,'count':40},
        {'fruits':grapes,'count':40},
        {'fruits':grapes,'count':40}]
```

Only it appending the last element

Comment: You are updating the same `dict` each time through the loop. Put `values = {}` *inside* the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def summary(request,):
    data = []
    fruits =  ['apple','mango','orange','grapes']
    for i in fruits:
        values = {}
        values['fruits'] = i
        values['count'] = calculating_count(i)
        data.append(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

```
def summary(request, ):
    fruits = ['apple', 'mango', 'orange', 'grapes']
    result = [{"fruits": fruit, "count": calculating_count(fruit)} for fruit in fruits]
```